# Unable to pass the data to php function using Ajax in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am unable to pass the data to a PHP function using ajax in jquery.

```
function updateinventory(product_code,user_id,id,outlet_id) {


var qtyid = 'qty_'+outlet_id;
//alert(product_code);

var dataString = {pcode:product_code};

var newqty = $('#qty_'+outlet_id).val(); 

//alert(newqty);

jQuery.ajax({
url: "<?=base_url()?>inventory/updateInventoryQtyFromProduct",
data: dataString,
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){

    console.log("success"+data);


 },
error:function (error){

    console.log(error);
}

 });

 }
```

and the PHP function is where I am trying to return the $pcode just to check if data is passing here or not.

```
public function updateInventoryQtyFromProduct()
{

 $pcode=$_POST['pcode'];
// $us_id=$_POST['user_id'];

 return $pcode;

}
```

Comment: receive the request first. example: `if(isset($_POST['pcode']))`

Comment: still getting error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort
:
ƒ (e)
always
:
ƒ ()
catch
:
ƒ (e)
done
:
ƒ ()
fail
:
ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
ƒ ()
getResponseHeader
:
ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType
:
ƒ (e)
pipe
:
ƒ ()
progress
:
ƒ ()
promise
:
ƒ (e)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
""
setRequestHeader
:
ƒ (e,t)
state
:
ƒ ()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
ƒ (e)
statusText
:
"OK"
then
:
ƒ (t,r,i)
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: @EmptyBrain error function result

Comment: How you saying that is error? `readyState : 4 `, ` status : 200` everything is fine. share your php code

Comment: public function updateInventoryQtyFromProduct()
    {
       
        if(isset($_POST['pcode'])){

       $pcode=$_POST['pcode'];
    // $us_id=$_POST['user_id'];

     return $pcode;


        }
   //  $pcode = $this->input->post('pcode');
    // $us_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

     

    }

Comment: public function updateInventoryQtyFromProduct()
    {
       
        if(isset($_POST['pcode'])){

       $pcode=$_POST['pcode'];

     return $pcode;


        }
   

    }

Comment: then why ajax error function is calling everytime

Comment: Bro seriously!! you need to learn the basic of request handling in php first. i already said receive the request first then send it to your function.

Comment: answer this question i will give +1 to you...

Comment: did you get the point? check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass like this :

```
  public function updateInventoryQtyFromProduct()
    {

     $pcode=$_POST['pcode'];
     echo json_encode($pcode);
     or  
     echo json_encode(array('pcode'=>$pcode)); //if array need

    }
```